# Amazon Personalize Expert

Tags: amazon-personalize

I want to recommend the Enhancement name  on the basis of what Massage name, HOw much service length , center name user select so i made this dataset please let me know is this correct

User datase
USER_ID AGE GENDER  ZIPCODE BASE_CENTER

ITEM dataset
ITEM id, ITEM name(Enhachment)

Interaction
USER_ID ITEM_ID TIMESTAMP   SERVICE_LENGTH  MASSAGE_NAME    CENTER_NAME EVENT_TYPE

*my one enhancement can belong to more than 1 massage name, center name

but the problem when i dont have user details
1.What should i pass in user id in input?
2.when i pass age and gender data then i get same result no affect

am i doing somthing wrong?